# Storing data to one table referencing two other tables

Tags: python, postgresql

I have the 3 tables in PostgreSQL database created as below:

```
--- "Balance sheet", etc..
CREATE TABLE statement (
[id]      int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[name]    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
companyId      int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (companyId) REFERENCES company ([id]),
);

--- "Tangible assets", "Outstanding stock", etc
CREATE TABLE statementRow (
[id]      int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
statementId int NOT NULL,
rowOrder  int NOT NULL,
rowTitle  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (statementId) REFERENCES statement ([id]),
);

--- The Facts
CREATE TABLE statementFact (
statementRowId int NOT NULL,
[date]         date NOT NULL,
amount         numeric NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([date], statementRow),
FOREIGN KEY (statementRowId) REFERENCES statementRow ([id])
);
```

The question is when I'm scraping a page and got a value "100" for some company let's say "AAA" in "balance sheet" statement for "inventory" row.

How i can connect all of these from the first two tables `statement` & `statementRow`tables to make sure that I'm inserting the value in `amount` column in the correct row beside the correct `statementRowId` column inside `statementFact` table using Python?

I tried many times but keeps getting the wrong value, anyone can help me with that ?

---

Update:

Last query i used :

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM statement AS st INNER JOIN statementsRow USING (statement_id)")
result = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]

query = "INSERT INTO statementsFact (date, amount) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cur.executemany(query, statementRowId)
con.commit()
```

Also i don't know if should use JOIN to connect data related or there is an easy way ?

---

To make the question more clear :

How can i insert value (`amount`) inside `statementFact` table with the right row (`statementRowId`), considering other related columns in other tables?

Comment: Do post your best attempt as well.

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry i forgot to post it, Question updated ..

Comment: Thanks that makes things clearer but this is still pretty dense; "How i can connect all of these from the first two tables statement & statementRowtables to make sure that I'm inserting the value in amount column in the correct row beside the correct statementRowId column inside statementFact table using Python?"

Comment: @e4c5 to make it more clear: how can i insert value ( `amount` ) inside `statementFact` table with the right `statementRowId`, concedring other related columns in other tables?